# gatsby-plugin-exclude not excluding test and mock files Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am working with `Gatsby`, I am trying to `exclude mocks and unit test case file from bundle`, with the help of `gatsby-plugin-exclude` plugin but its not working. I put below code in `gatsby-config.js`

```
   {
    resolve: "gatsby-plugin-exclude",
    options: { paths: ["/mocks/**"] },
   },
```

Also tried with this but no luck

```
 {
  resolve: "gatsby-plugin-advanced-sitemap",
  options: {
    exclude: [
      "/src/mocks/**",
    ],
  },
},
```

**Folder structure I am using:**

```
/src/mocks
/src/components/componentFolder/component.test.js
```

**I want to exclude all mocks and .test.js files from production bundle.**

Comment: FYI you misspelled components and have `compoenents` in your structure.